# Clean up a CSV file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, csv, replace

I have staff exporting data into CSV from one system, and using it to import content in our CMS.

The problem is that the CSV exports aren't formatted cleanly enough for our CSV import scripts.

Is jQuery capable of the following?

I'd like to convert, for example, a string like:

```
Hello,"Goodbye, Goodbye","Goodbye",Hello,Hello,Hello,"Goodbye, Goodbye"
```

To:

```
"Hello","Goodbye, Goodbye","Goodbye","Hello","Hello","Hello","Goodbye, Goodbye"
```

--so that every entry is consistently wrapped in quotations, not just entries that contain commas (`,`).

I've been using .replace(), but can't discover a consistent method to handle this problem.

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript. jQuery doesn't have many string utility functions.

Comment: @alex, any suggestions? Doesn't look like anyone else knows how to tackle this one.

Comment: You could write a simple parser, just needs to know if it's in *quotes* mode to split the CSV, or output a normalised version.

Comment: @alex In a nutshell, the goal is to wrap the unquoted entries in their own quotes (the `hello`s become `"hello"` in the above example). No need to touch the already quoted entries. http://jsfiddle.net/EKD39/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution, it will first find all correct occurence and replace them with a particular string

correct the improper string and then give the correct result

See the javascript Console to see the changes

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){

          OurTestData = 'Hello,"Goodbye, Goodbye","Goodbye",Hello,Hello,Hello,"Goodbye, Goodbye"';
          console.log(OurTestData);
            var pattern = /"([^"]+)"/g;
            var match;
            var MatchedArray = [];
            while(match = pattern.exec(OurTestData)) {
                MatchedArray.push(match[1]);
            }

             OurTestData = OurTestData.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, "CorrectSavedForLaterConversion");

             splittedArray = OurTestData.split(',');
             var preOutputString ="";

              preOutputString= '"' + splittedArray.join('" , "') + '"';



         /**
           Replace With Correct String
         */
           i=0;

         while(preOutputString.indexOf('CorrectSavedForLaterConversion') >= 0){

                preOutputString=  preOutputString.replace(/CorrectSavedForLaterConversion/,MatchedArray[i]) 
            i++;
          }

          console.log(preOutputString);

        });//]]>  

        </script>
```

Comment: Just to follow up, are you able to preserve line-breaks to determine the CSV headers? See http://jsfiddle.net/BW4Lj/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $("#text").val();
```

// Hello,"Goodbye, Goodbye","Goodbye",Hello,Hello,Hello,"Goodbye, Goodbye"

```
value = value.replace(',', '","');
```

// Hello",""Goodbye"," Goodbye"",""Goodbye"","Hello","Hello","Hello",""Goodbye"," Goodbye"

```
value = '"' + value + '"';
```

// "Hello",""Goodbye"," Goodbye"",""Goodbye"","Hello","Hello","Hello",""Goodbye"," Goodbye""

```
value = value.replace ('""','"');
```

// To replace all the double "" to single ". You will get your desired output

****Updated answer:****

**Replace** replaces only the first occurance of a particular string.
Try the following instead:

```
   var value =  $('#test').val();
   value = value.replace(/,/g, '","');
   value = '"' + value + '"';
   value = value.replace (/""/g,'"');
   $('#result').html(value);
```

Comment: thank you, although the output gives me: `"Hello","Goodbye, Goodbye","Goodbye",Hello,Hello,Hello,"Goodbye, Goodbye""` http://jsfiddle.net/EKD39/

Comment: value = value.replace(/,/g, '","');
   value = value.replace (/""/g,'"');
`/g` seems to have fixed :-)

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately this solution does not work, as it's not handling entries containing commas (`,`) correctly. It's splitting those entries into multiple entries.

Comment: Have a look at the updates. Replace replaces only the first occurance of string. Use the updated code to get what you want.

Comment: Hi Nisha, I had already corrected the code with `/g` but the major problem with it is that it's splitting entries, see my earlier response.